# Launch App Store in Apple TV

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, openurl, mfi

Is it possible to launch App Store in Apple TV from an external accessory which has MFi chip. I tried opening from my app using openURL

```
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

But I want to open from an external hardware accessory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using "**App Launch**" feature supported from tvOS 10.0.1.
tvOS 10.0.1 introduced support for App Launch, the ability for accessories to prompt users to launch or install companion apps just like on iOS. For example, MFi gaming controllers usually have companion apps that catalog compatible software and handle upgrading controller firmware.
When initially pairing an MFi gaming controller to Apple TV, tvOS could prompt the user to launch or install the companion app automatically.